# Style javascript forward link if current site is the most recent available

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, history

I'd like to change the font color of a JS-forward-button (history.forward()), if there is no newer site in history. Kinda like browsers forward-buttons.
Is there a way to achieve this? I want to keep it simple and avoid additional libraries except for jquery.

Currently I have these two links.

```
.navigation {color:#000}

<a href="javascript:history.back();" class="navigation">Back</a>
<a href="javascript:history.forward();" class="navigation">Forward</a>
```

Now if you visit the page for the first time and click on *back*, you get back to whereever you came from. But if you click on *forward*, nothing happens, because, of course, you are already on top of the history. So I look for a way to give the forward link a {color:#666} in this case.
If the user navigated a bit on the site and clicked *back* at some point, he is able to go forward in history again and the link should get a {color:#000}.
That is exactly what the chrome context menu, for example, does.
Any chances?

Comment: Bare in mind it really helps to see any code you've currently been working on. This will help people be able to give you an accurate answer

Comment: Post the HTML code for your button and someone can give you an answer specific to your selector.